# Testing with Karma Node V 6.0.0

Tags: node.js, karma-jasmine

Any suggestions on testing with NODE V6.0.0? I am currently, using karma and Jasmin in client side and wondering if I can still reuse the karmaconfig file from root to reuse for the server side testing. 
I don't think I would need to use Babel to compile now that NODE 6 is es6 friendly.

In advance, Thank you